# Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:bundle:2.9.8

Tags: jackson

Working with Jackson library, it came following error in Eclipse 4.9.0 version

Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:bundle:2.9.6   pom.xml /Jackson-Usage  line 7  Maven Dependency Problem

The problem came when I added maven dependencies by GUI to add dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

The solution was from generated dependencies

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

to remove and save.

```
<type>bundle</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

`xml`

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
      <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

Remove **bundle** and that should resolve the error code in eclipse.